# Convert to .cap error- invalid AID 1.0 in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, smartcard, javacard

This is the source code that I want to upload to my card :

```
import javacard.framework.APDU;
import javacard.framework.Applet;
import javacard.framework.ISOException;


public class ReadMemo extends Applet {
    private ReadMemo() {
    }
    public static void install(byte bArray[], short bOffset, byte bLength)
            throws ISOException {
        new ReadMemo().register();
    }

    public void process(APDU arg0) throws ISOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

As you see, the program do nothing! but why when I want to convert it to **.cap** file, I receive this error :
**invalid AID 1.0**

[image]

**Note :**

my package ID : `0x00:0x01:0x02:0x03:0x04:0x05:0x06:0x07`

my applet ID  : `0x00:0x01:0x02:0x03:0x04:0x05:0x06:0x07:0x08`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your code out of the default package (*never* use the default package in Java). Because the `package_name` argument is empty, the arguments have been shifted to the left, and it will now see the version number as an AID. Hence the strange error.